# How to safely parse json object coming through websockets?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, security, parsing

My node.js server is expecting to receive stringified JSON object from a non authenticated (not trusted) client.

The server uses JSON.parse to process the data.
is it possible to inject "threatening and manipulating " orders within the JOSN data coming from the websocket  ?

is there any security precautions to consider ?

is there any thing like "htmlspecialchars() in php" in the javascript parsing?

Server:

```
wsBoss = new WSServer(portboss);
wsBoss.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log('connected to boss');
socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(msg).topGeo[0]);
    var msgsms="HI";
    socket.send(msgsms);
});
```

Client:

```
var data={"topGeo":topGeo,
          "bottomGeo":bottomGeo,
          "concLoad":concLoad}
console.log(topGeo,bottomGeo,depth,generalLoad,concLoad,intervLoad,mode,joistType,units);
websocket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several suggestions:

1. Limit amount of data read by your server to prevent DoS attacks (via out of memory errors).
2. Limit number of requests, throttle input to prevent DoS (via handling too many incorrect/malformed requests).
3. Use strict JSON validator to prevent malformed data. is-my-json-valid provides robust validation based on JSONSchema. https://github.com/mafintosh/is-my-json-valid

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` itself is considered to protect its users from the malicious attacks of the older ways like `eval`-ling the JSON to convert its string value into an object. However, it is still important that it can't protect program's authors from accidental security issues in the code processing the received objects. However, in that sense deserialized from JSON objects are no different to "normal" code-created objects. Furthermore, no JavaScript interpreter has absolute security as problems are found from time to time, so there is some risk that someone would find a security issue in V8's `JSON.parse` implementation. Having that said, it is highly unlikely that a custom self-written parsing algorithm would be safer than a proven open-source one deployed to millions of installations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.